# Visual C++ open Dialog Box when button clicked

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog

So I am new to programming in C++ and new to using Visual Studio 2010. Basically I have a FLIR thermal camera; and I need to edit a GUI provided in an eBUS SDK that suits my needs.

What I want to do is open a new dialog box when I click the settings button. I am just not sure what code to use in the button handler to make the dialog box open. I have put different code in the button handler to test it and the settings button works fine.

This is the button handler that the code needs to go into.

```
void PvSimpleUISampleDlg::OnBnClickedSettings()
{

}
```

This is the dialog box in the resource file that I want to connect the button to. It is called `IDD_SETTINGS`. The actual button is called `IDB_SETTINGS`, not sure if that's relevant.

```
IDD_SETTINGS DIALOGEX 0, 0, 506, 300
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Settings"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,449,279,50,14

END
```

I am not sure what other code to add, but I am completely new so any help/advice you can give no matter how small would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the MFC framework (the CDialog class), then you can create a new CDialog object using the settings-dialog resource you've created.

The `CDialog::DoModal()` function is what you want, if you want a simple popup box that grabs your attention until it is dismissed with OK or Cancel.

In your source file:

```
void PvSimpleUISampleDlg::OnBnClickedSettings()
{
    CDialog mySettings( IDD_SETTINGS );
    INT_PTR returnCode = -1;
    returnCode = mySettings.DoModal();

    switch( returnCode ) {
    case IDOK :
      //gather your input fields here 

      break;
    case IDCANCEL :
      //do something
      break;

    case -1:
    default:
       //error creating box
    }
}
```

Here is a link for using the CDialog class as a starting point for extracting information from the box once OK is clicked:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what i wanted!